# Allocating memory in C for a fortran array

Tags: c, fortran

I am new to fortran programming.. I have a 3 dimensional array declared as follows

```
REAL*4, DIMENSION(:,:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: a1
```

I want to pass the array by reference to a C or C++ function and allocate memory in C rather than in fortran. Is it possible or I am wrong in understanding the array concept in fortran ?

Comment: It certainly should be possible, but you need to understand well how such fortran arrays are implemented.

Comment: If [that](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html) can help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends, but probably not, depending on your circumstances.  Definitely not in a portable way, if you are limited to Fortran 90 as per the question tag.

Note that your Fortran variable is an ALLOCATABLE.

As you've asked, it requires a Fortran compiler (and companion C compiler) that implement the relatively recently published Technical Specification ([TS 29113:2012](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/TS29113Status)).  You are operating at the bleeding edge of the development of the language - and the number of compilers that currently support this TS is small (if not zero).  It is expected that the contents of this TS would be incorporated into next revision of the Fortran standard, so try again in a few years time and you might have better luck.

Note though, that the TS limits the way in which C can do the allocation for Fortran - basically the C code needs to call a Fortran compiler supplied routine.  You can not use any old allocator (including malloc), so this still may not suit.

However, Fortran 2003 added the possibility for the memory allocation of Fortran POINTER's (not allocatables as you've asked) to be done in C.  The C code returns a pointer to a chunk of memory of the appropriate size, which the Fortran procedure receives back as object of type C_PTR.  The Fortran code then calls the procedure C_F_POINTER to associate the C address in the C_PTR object with the Fortran pointer.  C_PTR and C_F_POINTER are entities in the intrinsic ISO_C_BINDING module.

A crude example:

```
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR, C_F_POINTER
INTERFACE
  FUNCTION get_some_memory() BIND(C, NAME='get_some_memory')
    IMPORT :: C_PTR
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: get_some_memory
  END FUNCTION get_some_memory
END INTERFACE

! REAL*4 isn't Fortran.  Correct syntax below.
REAL(4), POINTER, DIMENSION(:,:,:) :: a1

! get_some_memory would typically be told how much memory was needed.
! n1, n2, n3 are integer with the relevant extents for each dimension.
CALL C_F_POINTER(get_some_memory(), a1, [n1,n2,n3])

! Equivalent call to free required at some later stage.


void *get_some_memory()
{
  return malloc(some_number_of_bytes);   
}
```

Beyond this, there are processor dependent (i.e. non-portable) tricks that you can play, but they are outside of the standard language.

Comment: Thanks @IanH.. Ur example was helpful.. Fortunately my installed gcc compiler supports the Technical Specification (T229113:2012) that u mentioned and it works..

Comment: The example only uses Fortran 2003.  gfortran developers are still working on TS 29113 support.

Answer (score 3):

As the [answer by IanH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389336) says, the
Technical Specification TS 29113 allows a way for the allocation of a Fortran allocatable object to be performed in a C function, this having a lasting effect on the Fortran side.

Since that earlier answer was written support for this TS has increased (although it's still not large and the C descriptor part we'll use in this answer is notably not supported by current gfortran).  That means it's now probably worth writing an example.  This example is not valid under Fortran 2008.

We consider the C structure given by `CFI_desc_t` (from the source file `ISO_Fortran_binding.h`) and the C function `CFI_allocate`.

Assume that our allocation of the rank-3 array occurs in a C procedure compatible with the following Fortran interface

```
interface
   subroutine allocating_sub(x) bind(c)
     use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_float
     real(c_float), allocatable :: x(:,:,:)
   end subroutine allocating_sub
end interface
```

We note that such a Fortran interface is compatible with a C function prototype which has the formal argument as a pointer to `CFI_cdesc_t`.

Define this C function as (with magic numbers, and missing lots of 
other sensible checking and such):

```
#include "ISO_Fortran_binding.h"

void allocating_sub(CFI_cdesc_t* x) {
  if (x->base_addr) CFI_deallocate(x);
  CFI_index_t lower[3]={-1, 5, 1};
  CFI_index_t upper[3]={20, 9, 5};
  CFI_allocate(x, lower, upper, 0);
}
```

`CFI_index_t` is a "typedef name for a standard signed integer type capable of representing the result of subtracting two pointers".

Allocation happens with the `CFI_allocate` function which here allocates `x` with the lower and upper bounds given by the obvious variables.  The final number (`0`) is ignored in our case with `x` not corresponding to a Fortran character type.

To complete the example, take the Fortran program:

```
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_float
  implicit none

  interface
     subroutine allocating_sub(x) bind(c)
       import c_float
       real(c_float), allocatable :: x(:,:,:)
     end subroutine allocating_sub
  end interface

  integer i
  real(c_float), allocatable :: x(:,:,:)

  allocate(x(6,2,5))
  print 1, (LBOUND(x,i), UBOUND(x,i), i=1,3)

  call allocating_sub(x)
  if (allocated(x)) print 1, (LBOUND(x,i), UBOUND(x,i), i=1,3)

1 format ("x has been allocated like x(",2(I0,":",I0,","),I0,":",I0,").")

end
```

The example is a little non-minimal as it also shows the `CFI_deallocate` function and the fact that, although we have this extra level on the C side, we can still access the memory in that C function through the component `x->base_addr`.  This is a null pointer if the Fortran variable is not allocated; otherwise it's the C address of the first element of the Fortran array, as long as there is at least one element.

Much more detail can be found in the TS document or the draft upcoming Fortran standard.

Answer (score 1):

ALLOCATABLE's have been in Fortran since F90 for the most part, and so quite "ancient" (not quite bleeding edge at 25+ years old).

However, just out of curiosity, why is the mem allocation required on the c-side?  If you need that array on the F-side, it will need to be allocated or otherwise declared some space on the F-side at some point.

Also, you may not actually need an Allocatable.  You may find Automatic arrays more convenient.  For example:

```
Subroutine sr(ArrayA, Answer, iJunk)
    Real(4), Intent(In)    :: ArrayA(:,:)   ! immediately has correct dims etc
    Integer, Intent(In)    :: iJunk
    Real(4), Intent(Out)   :: Answer
    !
    ! locals
    !
    Real(4)                :: ArrayB(Size(ArrayA, Dim = 1))   ! AUTOMATIC array declared "on the fly" with order of that of the leading dimension of ArrayA, for example.
    Real(4)                :: ArrayC(iJunk)                   ! another way to create "dynamic" arrays
    !
    ! ... do stuff
End Subroutine sr          ! All automatic (and allocatables) are cleared/destroyed "automatically" since F95, with F90 you should manually DeAllocate allocated arrays.
```

This can be done before or after your c call, so if c returns the dims required, you can "auto", or allocate as suits.

Not sure if that helps, as I am not sure I have grasped the essence of your objective.

Also, just food for thought, while ISO binding is generally a good idea, it can cause some headaches.  For example, in many cases (with ISO) you must pass strings as single char arrays, c.f. a singe string with n chars.  This can be a bit of grief, especially if you have an array of strings, etc.  The mixed language bits can be accomplished without ISO, in some cases for much less "cost".