# julia: How do you correctly align array memory when using unsafe_store! to write a struct array to a c or fortran program?

Tags: struct, memory-management, fortran, julia

I have a julia program, which opens a fortran shared object library, writes to a global type(struct) array and then calls a function, which accesses this variable.
The problem is that the values entered in the julia struct do not correspond to the values extracted in the fortran code:

`test.jl:`

```
using Base.Libc.Libdl
using Base.Libc

mutable struct jul_param
    f1::Float64
    f2::Float64
    testbool::Bool
end

try
    # create jul_param struct array of size 2 and store pointer in ptr_jul_struct_array
    testparam = jul_param(1.0, 2.0, true)
    ptr_jul_struct_array = convert(Ptr{jul_param}, calloc(2, sizeof(jul_param)))
    unsafe_store!(ptr_jul_struct_array,testparam,1)
    unsafe_store!(ptr_jul_struct_array,testparam,2)

    # fetch the memory address of global allocatable test_param type array in fortran 
    testmodule_bin = Libdl.dlopen("testmodule.so")
    test_param_sym = Libdl.dlsym(testmodule_bin, Symbol("__testmodule_MOD_test_param"))
    ptr_fortran_type_array = convert(Ptr{Ptr{jul_param}}, test_param_sym)
    unsafe_store!(ptr_fortran_type_array, ptr_jul_struct_array)

    # call test_func in fortran program
    function_sym = Libdl.dlsym(testmodule_bin, Symbol("__testmodule_MOD_test_func"))
    ccall(function_sym,Cvoid,())
catch e
    println("Error: ", e)
    rethrow(e)
end
```

`testmodule.f90:`

```
module testmodule

  type :: JulParam
    real :: &
      f1, &
      f2
    logical :: &
      testbool
  end type JulParam

  type(JulParam),     allocatable, dimension(:) :: test_param

  contains

  module subroutine test_func()
    print *, "test size", size(test_param) !returns 1 instead of 2
    print *, "test val1", test_param(1)%f1 !returns random floats that change on every call instead of 1.0
  end subroutine test_func

end module testmodule
```

I am using this command to run this program:

`gfortran -fpic -c testmodule.f90 &&  gfortran -shared -o testmodule.so testmodule.o && julia test.jl`

Is there a way to convert the memory layout of the julia struct so it can be read properly from within the fortran program?

Comment: For those of us who know practically nothing about Julia, why would we expect `teststring::String` and `character(len=256), allocatable, dimension(:) :: teststring` to have the slightest similarity?

Comment: What you are doing is inherently non-portable (even across different versions of GCC), so can you explain how general you want to be, how much you are able to redesign things, and similar?

Comment: @francescalus I removed the string definition from this post. By redesigning, do you mean modifying the fortran code? The idea was to unittest singular functions in my fortran program without having to use some kind of fortran based unittest framework, so my goal would be to recreate an environment that the function would execute in at runtime, e.g. by filling module variables such as `test_param` with testvalues before running a function that uses it for something.

Comment: (Again, consider my comments completely Julia-naive.) Without using (C-)interoperable facility you are totally at the whim of things you have to assume you don't know, especially if you're trying to unit test on multiple platforms. Consider, `type(julparam) x(2)`: is `x(1)%f2` 32 bytes after `x(1)%f1`, or `x(2)%f1` 96 bytes after `x(1)%f1`. You cannot know. `calloc(2, sizeof(jul_param))` seems to be saying that you expect `test_param` to be simply twice the length of those three components. It almost surely won't be, but you won't have a clue how long it actually is: array descriptor/dope.

Comment: @francescalus I see, so you would not recommend this approach to unittesting? I assumed that it would be a viable option considering the lack of flexibility of current frameworks, especially for larger projects.

Comment: Allocating a C-interoperable Fortran array in C is [painful enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37837472/3157076)...

Comment: If you're doing the unit testing this way because you think it'll make things easy, then consider that it won't be easy at all; if you're doing this because you have no choice than you have an interesting question.

Comment: You may adapt this example of C calling Fortran with structures and allocatables, with Julia instead of C (but I don't have enough knowledge in Julia to know it's transposable or not): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75242877/shared-data-structure-between-c-and-fortran-adding-allocatable-arrays/75258978#75258978 . The general idea is that C/Julia doesn't try to mimic the structures, but uses wrapper routines. This is not simple, though...

Answer (score 0):

You are defining allocatable variables: test_param and teststring, which are not allocated. For example, allocate(test_param(2)), to assign 2 members for test_param, see the code below. Note that variable, teststring, is not a string but rather an allocatable array of string (len=256). So, you need also to allocate it.

```
module testmodule

    implicit none

    type :: JulParam
      real :: &
        f1, &
        f2
      logical :: &
        testbool
      character(len=256), allocatable, dimension(:) :: &
        teststring
    !   character(len=256) :: &
    !     teststring
    end type JulParam
  
    type(JulParam),     allocatable, dimension(:) :: test_param
    ! type(JulParam) :: test_param
  
    ! private
    ! public :: test_func

    contains
  
    module subroutine test_func()

        ! real :: mat(10, 10)

        ! print *, mat
        
        type(JulParam),  allocatable, dimension(:) :: test_param 

        allocate(test_param(2))
        allocate(character(len=256) :: test_param(1)%teststring(2))

        ! type(JulParam) :: test_param

        print *, "test size", size(test_param) !returns 1 instead of 2
        print *, "test val1", test_param(1)%f1 !returns random floats that change on every call instead of 1.0
        print *, "test val2", test_param(1)%teststring !generates segmentation fault
    end subroutine test_func
  
end module testmodule
```

Comment: The whole point of the OP is that they want to allocate and populate the structure on the Julia side, and call the Fortran routine from Julia. So I can't see how allocating on the Fortran side like this may be a solution...